# dynamic edittext when is destroyed android

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-edittext

I'm writing spreadsheet app for android and for getting cell value i use dynamic edittext.
Is this any way to get info when text is written and save it to cell value?

here is part of code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    if(Selection != null) {
        Cell prevSelection = hostActivity.logic.getCell(Selection.left, Selection.top);
        SelTxt = hostActivity.txtInput.getText().toString();

        if(SelTxt.length() != 0 && prevSelection.GetValue() != SelTxt && prevSelection.getChanged()) {
            prevSelection.setValue(SelTxt);
            hostActivity.txtInput.clearComposingText();
            prevSelection.Modified(false);
            SelTxt = "";
        }
    }


    switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

            calculateSelectionRect(x, y);
            SelectionChanged = true;

            if(x > startTableX && y > startTableY && !GroupSelected) {
                Cell tmpCell = hostActivity.logic.getCell(Selection.left, Selection.top);
                hostActivity.EditSelectedCellValue(Selection.left, Selection.top, Selection.right, Selection.bottom, tmpCell);
            }
        invalidate();
```

and

```
        if(txtInput != null)
        frameLayout.removeView(txtInput);

    String tmpText = "";
    txtInput = new EditText(this.getApplicationContext());

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams txtParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((right - left), (bottom - top));
    txtInput.setX(left);
    txtInput.setY(top);
    txtInput.setText(value.GetValue());
    txtInput.setTextColor(R.color.Selected_Cell_Border);
    txtInput.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Selected_Cell));

    frameLayout.addView(txtInput, txtParams);
    setContentView(frameLayout);

    tmpText = txtInput.getText().toString();

    if(txtInput.getText().toString() != value.GetValue())
        value.Modified(true);

    txtInput.clearComposingText();
    return tmpText;
}
```

in app it works in a way that after filling one cell and selecting cell directly below value is copied once, another selecting this cell gives good empty cell and is ok. But it's annoying and shouldn't happen

Comment: What's about a TextView?

Have a look at this Method `addTextChangedListener`, here you're able to detect when the user changes the Text. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)

Comment: TextChangedListener work with edittext too.

Comment: no that won't help, but maybe it would be better just for existing cells to add new textedits? Would it be killing for phone?

Comment: Solved it :) Problem was in a function getting selected cell